# eigenvalues of a 6x6 matrix with many zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for the eigenvalues of a $6\times 6$ real matrix, which is of the form
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 &0 &\gamma_1 &0\\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0&0&0&\gamma_2\\
. & .& \lambda_3 &0&0&0\\
. & .& . &\lambda_4 &0&0\\
. & .& . &.&\lambda_5&0\\
. & .& . &.&0&\lambda_6
\end{bmatrix}
.$$
The dots stand for other unknown real parameters.

There are many way to characterize this matrix. It is the sum of triangular matrix and a nilpotent matrix for instance. You can also study this matrix as a block matrix of $3\times3$ matrices. I spent a lot of time finding a relevant decomposition to apply a property. I also try to solve for the characteristic polynomial but it was unsuccessful.

I am particularly interested in the signs of $M$'s eigenvalues. It may be possible to say something about them without finding explicit solutions. I know that $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are nonpositive, and $\lambda_4$, $\lambda_5$ and $\lambda_6$ are non negative. I wish I could have a condition for $M$ to have $3$ eigenvalues positive and $3$ negative.

Comment: Do the dots stand for 0's or for any complex numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure what to assume here.  You have written that M can be written as the sum of a triangular and a nilpotent but this is true of every matrix. On the other hand, if the dots are zeros and this matrix is upper triangular, then the eigenvalues are already the values on the diagonal.

Comment: I just edited the post. The dots stand for real parameters. Knowing that every matrix is a T+N matrix now sounds obvious to me. Thanks for raising the point.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to characterize this as a rank-2 perturbation of a lower-triangular matrix.  I don't happen to know if that lets you say anything nice, though